# How to drive app config value via my test scenario

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In the app.config file of my Selenium-Specflow-Nunit framework I have a key to set customer value (e.g. Walmart, Amazon, BestBuy, etc). To run my test against each of these customers I need to change the key value in app.config file everytime. That means I can't run the test for all customers at one run and controlled from my Specflow scenario.

Wondering is there a way to drive and control the customer key value of config file from the test?

Answer (score 1):

One way I do this is to create a method like this:

**(untested)**

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void InitAppConfig(string customerValue)
    {
       var config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
       config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("Customer");
       config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Customer", customerValue);
       config.Save();
       ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
    }
```

Comment: I am unable to get WebConfigurationManager. Is there a specific collection that I have to call?

Comment: Noted that Remove is not necessary as it removes the string. I have included the solution I arrived upon (above) and is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Used the below code

```
 public void ModifyAppConfig(string customer, string env)
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;           
        config.Set("CUSTOMER", customer);            
        config.Set("Environment", environment);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

    }
```